# How can I make the headings in xelatex document align at the left?

Tags: emacs, latex, indentation, org-mode, xelatex

[image]

Hello, I'm using Emacs's org mode for editing my documents. As you can see I have a first level heading (the blueish color) and a second level heading (yellow).

My table of contents doesn't show up and I have no idea why, but the biggest issue is aligning those headings to the left in the PDF and make them bold.

I'm using the following xelatex settings in the Emacs config if this helps:

```
"article"
"\\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
                  \\usepackage{fontspec}
                  \\setmainfont{Charis SIL}
                  \\usepackage{geometry}
                  \\geometry{a4paper, left=0.67in, right=0.67in,
                             top=0.5in, bottom=0.67in}
                  \\setlength{\\parindent}{0pt}
```

Here's the content of the .TEX file that is also generated along the PDF.

```
% Created 2020-11-14 Sat 22:47
% Intended LaTeX compiler: xelatex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
                \usepackage{fontspec}
                \setmainfont{Charis SIL}
                \usepackage{geometry}
                \geometry{a4paper, left=0.67in, right=0.67in,
                           top=0.5in, bottom=0.67in}
                \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\title{Test Document}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={Author},
 pdftitle={Test Document},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 27.1 (Org mode 9.3)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

Org mode, as it says on the official web page is for keeping notes, maintaining TODO lists, doing project planning, and authoring with a fast and effective plain-text system. Beginning with Emacs 22.2 and XEmacs 22.1 it has been part of Emacs. The following is a simple tutorial to help you get started using Emacs and Org mode.

\begin{enumerate}
\item The absolute minimum you need to know about Emacs
\label{sec:orgf515372}

The absolute minimum you need to know about Emacs, to be able to do anything, is more then you need to know about many other applications. But, you might compare it to a regular toy and lego. Lego is harder to begin with (you start with a box with little plastic pieces), but in the long run, you can do more with it.

Emacs is heavy on shortcuts. starting out, that is rather annoying, but in time you'll notice you start to use the mouse less and less, and you actually start to work quicker.

\begin{enumerate}
\item Starting Org mode
\label{sec:orgb4df8b1}

New shortcuts in this chapter:

C-x C-s – save document
C-x C-f – open document
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you access the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: Yes,  I updated my post. When I export, the .tex file is also generated, but it would be nicer to have it formatted through Emacs itself. Org mode in Emacs accepts basically any tex flag, I just don't know where to look. I checked the xelatex docs but haven't found anything about heading indentation, only about paragraph indentation. As you can see I set first line of the paragraphs to zero indendation as well `\setlength{\\parindent}{0pt}` because I don't need it.

Comment: Can you try to add `\usepackage{enumitem} \setlist[enumerate]{left=0pt}` to your config? (maybe with double `\\ ` instead) (you won't find anything for headings, because these are no headings but enumerate items). As for the table of contents: you need to use sections, chapters or similar if you want a table of contents, enumerations won't show up there. I don't know org mode, but maybe try with `#` for headings?

Comment: Yes, I did thaht and I posted a new picture at the bottom of my post. The headlings are on the left but the paragraphs are still indented to align with the headings. Does xelatex use enumerate things? I would like them to be headings.

Comment: enumerate is not for headings. For headings use chapters, sections etc. Enumerate is for (more or less) small enumerated lists, like 1. try that, 2. try that

Comment: Hello. I fixed it. I found this website http://nickguthrie.com/archives/276 and added those `("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")` lines to my config now it works. I also removed the numbers. I don't like having numbered items in the TOC I rely on their indentation for TOC just like Github does in a markdown file. The PDF exporter in AsciiDoc also excludes them, although they may be important for scientific, technical stuff, and books.

Comment: The question is why those `section/subsection/etc` entries were missing in the first place:  by default, `org-latex-classes` has them.